# In a BST how can I keep an array as a value?

Tags: c, file, key, binary-search-tree

I am reading a file where the first word that appears on the line is the one that I want as a key.
The other words, I want to keep them in an array of `chars(char* array[])`.

The problem I have is, when the key is repeated in another line of the file, so I want to add the other words to next position of the array.

How can I do that?

```
FILE* file1 = fopen(name_file,"r");
if(!file1) return 1;

bst_t* bst = bst_create(strcmp,NULL);
if(!bst) return 1;

char* line = NULL;
size_t count = 0;
ssize_t read;

while((read = getline(&line,&count,file1)) > 0){
    char** arr_line = split(line,' ');
    char* key = arr_line[0];
    char* value = arr_line[1];

    if(!bst_find(bst,key)){
        char** values = malloc(sizeof(char*));
        values[0] = value;

        bst_insert(bst,key,&values);
    }
    else{
        ///?
    }

    free_strv(arr_line);
}

free(line);
fclose(file1);

return 0;
```

Comment: Please show, what have you tried?

Comment: So when you read the key, you need to search the BST to find the node. If not found, add a new node with the key to the BST. Then you need to append the other words on the line to the array in the new or existing node. Are you using fixed size arrays or are you allocating them dynamically? If dynamic, you may need to use `realloc` to increase the size of the array if it is not long enough to hold the appended words.

Comment: I am allocating them dynamically. How can I access to the value that I already insert so then I can use realloc?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a pointer that you increment whenever you add to the char* array[ ], or everytime you want to add more strings, you create a new string array with malloc, and copy everything to the new array **in addition** to all of the new strings.

It really depends on your existing code and how it behaves. (otherwise I'd be more specific)